# What is the best way to fetch mails for a client app?

Tags: ios, api, email, security, server

I'm creating an e-mail client for iOS and before the start of working on it, I want to select the best architecture for it.

For example, at the first stage, I want to connect Gmail. I searched and found that Google has a ready library for doing that, so I can just connect the library and fetch my emails.

Another way of doing that is fetching emails from the API in my web server and later to take these emails from my server.

The main purpose is not just to fetch emails, but to be able later to add some new filtrations to it or some other functionalities, maybe machine learning technologies for better personalisation, etc.

Also, I want to support multiple email servers(Gmail, Yahoo, Hotmail, etc.)

What do you advise me to choose, to fetch from my own server or directly from the email servers? I also understand the security issues in the case of using my own servers.

Your feedbacks will help me a lot! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use your own server for this task. You just don't need it. It's less secure and I'm pretty sure, that some of your clients will dislike the fact, that you can store their mails on your own server.

If you want to support multiple email server providers, then you should use IMAP protocol for receiving mails and SMTP for sending. Also, in some cases, you can use OAuth2 as authentication method, so you don't need to ask user to enter his credentials in your application.

I recommend you to use some open source libraries for working with IMAP and SMTP, because implementing this protocols by self can be complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds very similar to what I was doing. I was recently building [PickedMail](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pickedmail/id1244830423?mt=8) where the backend is heavy AI. For Google, you'll want to use Oauth2 and use the server_token to pass in to your server.

I created an iOS framework for this, hope that helps you. https://github.com/Thywis/MultiAccountOauth

For others like outlook, yahoo, iCloud, I'd suggest using IMAP for now.